# Question about Scalar products for $p=\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b$ and $A=a$

Tags: vectors

may I know what is the scalar product for $\vec{p}=\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b$, $\vec{A}=a$. Should we say $a \cdot p = \lambda a^2 +(1-\lambda) a\times b $ or $a \cdot p=\lambda a^2 +(1-\lambda) a\cdot b$.

Thank you very much for replying to the question, I am quite confused with the concept of the dot product here.

Comment: if $a$ is meant to be a vector, then $a^2$ doesn't have a clear meaning.  If you want, you can use $|a|^2$ or just $a\cdot a$.  And...why would the cross product appear?  The dot product is linear so, with the change for "$a^2$", the second calculation is correct.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much, I will correct my notation, sorry for any inconvenience caused. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product distributes, so $\bf a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$. The second expression is correct.

As a sidenote, you seem to have used the symbol $a$ to mean both the vector $\bf a$, as in $a\cdot p$, and its magnitude, as in $a^2$. You may use `\vec a` for $\vec a$ or `\mathbf a` for $\bf a$, to indicate that '$a$' refers to a vector. You can use $|\mathbf a|,|\vec a|$ or just $a$ to denote its magnitude.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, and, May I ask one more question, for dot product such as $\lambda \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, can we say it is the same as $\lambda (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})$

Comment: @HenryCai Yes, that is true. If you are satisfied with any answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark button on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $a$ and $b$ are vectors so I will use $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ instead.

$\vec{p}. \vec{A} = \left ( \lambda \vec{a} + (1 - \lambda) \vec{b} \right ). \vec{a} $
$ =\lambda \vec{a}.\vec{a} + (1 - \lambda)\vec{a}.\vec{b} $

In case $\vec{a}$ $\perp$ $\vec{b}$, then this reduces to $\vec{p}. \vec{A} = \lambda \vec{a}. \vec{a}$

With a further assumption that $\vec{a}$ is a unit vector, then $\vec{p}. \vec{A} = \lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.